# Copy text that only selectable with 3 fingers tap

Tags: trackpad, copy-paste

On my Mac Yosemite 10.10.5, I can tap 3 fingers to lookup for a word. That lookup could select text from virtually anywhere. I would like to copy that text to clipboard instead of doing lookup. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just right click and copy. Or highlight the word(s) and press command-C

Comment: Three finger tap can select text from Label, which normally won't let you highlight with simple left/right click action.